# organize collected entries in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with answers of a survey. Each person answers 3 questions. Unfortunately, each line of the dataframe correspond to an answer of a question, rather than a person entry.

How can I reformat that?

Currently I have a dataframe that has columns set as:

`person_id`, `person_name`, `person_age`, `question`, `answer`.

Each entry in this dataframe is a person's answer to a single question.

I would like for each entry to be all of that person's answers. So the columns would be more like

`person_id`, `person_name`, `person_age`, `question1`, `question2`,`question3`

I don't have much code or error to share because I barely know how should I go about solving this problem, or how is that logic that I should be using.

But instead of having a dataframe that look like:

```
001___james___20___Question1____maybe
001___james___20___Question2____sure
001___james___20___Question3____no
003___anne___22___Question2____sure
003___anne___22___Question3____no
```

I would like to have it look like:

```
001___james___20___maybe___sure___no
003___anne___22___[BLANK]___sure___no
```

Comment: Have you seen the pandas pivot tables function?  I think that will serve you nicely.

 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html

Comment: @jtweeder,i had not seen it! I helped on a big part of the problem! Thanks! Now i just need to find out how to match the ```person_name``` and ```person_age``` to the ```person_id``` that i used as index in the pivot table!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler way to do is to use `unstack` with `set index`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,'James', 20, 'question 1', 'Yes'],
    [1,'James', 20, 'question 2', 'No'],
    [1,'James', 20, 'question 3', 'Maybe'],
    [2,'Elle', 20, 'question 1', 'No'],
    [2,'Elle', 20, 'question 2', 'Yes'],
    [2,'Elle', 20, 'question 3', 'Maybe']
], columns = ['person_id', 'person_name','person_age','question', 'answer'])

df = df.set_index(['person_id','person_name','person_age','question'])['answer'].unstack()
```

Output

```py
question                         question 1 question 2 question 3
person_id person_name person_age                                 
1         James       20                Yes         No      Maybe
2         Elle        20                 No        Yes      Maybe
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Split the dataframe on "Question", and on "____" (four underscores, so that you have a dataframe with 3 columns.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Step 2) Use the pivot table functionality mentioned by jtweeded.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: And technically, Step 3) concatenate the pivoted columns to match your specific desired output.